# Give an example of an injective ring homomorphism $f : R \to S$ where $R$ is commutative, but $S$ is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

I feel like matrices would be the right way to go for something that doesn't commute. However, the matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a \end{pmatrix}$$

commutes.

Comment: Were you trying to show that the image of the homomorphism is not a commutative subring? (This can't be done!) Otherwise, your thinking works just fine (with $b = 0$, as the answers below suggest).

Answer (score 7):

Consider any diagonal embedding $R\longrightarrow M_n(R)$ for $n>1$, i.e. send $r\mapsto {\rm diag}(r,\ldots,r)$. A simpler example is $Z(R)\hookrightarrow R$ for any noncommutative ring $R$!

Answer (score 4):

You should be aware of the fact that your homomorphism *must not* be surjective. You're probably thinking to
$$
\mathbb{C}\to M_2(\mathbb{R}),
\qquad
a+bi\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ -b &a\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a good example.

Easier, the map
$$
F\to M_2(F),
\qquad
a\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 &a\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $F$ is a field and $M_2(F)$ is the ring of $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: However my problem is that the matrix you just cited is commutative! That's why i thought I couldnt' use it

Comment: @user273301 What do you mean by “the matrix is commutative”? It doesn't make sense, does it? Of course $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ commutes with every matrix, but this is of no consequence with respect to the problem.